# "Down" Casting columns while doing a UNION ALL (MS Sql Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

According to the SQL type conversion chart found at (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) all of the data types I'm using can be *implicitly* converted to the nvarchar type.  This is ideal for my purposes, therefore I expected that this would work, thinking that #CSV_Column_Titles would determine the type of all columns:

```
INSERT INTO #CSV_Output          
SELECT * from #CSV_Column_Titles   --  n" columns, all columns are nvarchar( MAX ) )
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #QueryResults       --  "n" columns, all must be implicitly converted to nvarchar( MAX )
```

however this returns messages like :

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 120
Error converting data type nvarchar to float.
```

I know why this happens; for what I'm trying to do the conversion precedence rules (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) are "backwards". I expected  that  implicit conversion would "downcast" from the most specific/restrictive form to the most general form - which would meet my needs.

The code fragment above is from a procedure that creates a "CSV style" table.  Implicit conversion (to nvarchar) would be ideal because #QueryResults is being passed in as a parameter and it can have any number of columns of any type.  (For those who are curious, #CSV_Column_Titles is created by using dynamic SQL to extract the column titles from #QueryResults.)

I tried to get around the precedence issue by creating a used defined type (an alias to nvarchar) but was denied "create" permission (and know it will never be granted).

Before I look any farther into using dynamic SQL, is there some easy way to (ideally implicitly) "downcast" each column to nvarchar without having to use explicit casts/converts?

---

BTW, If I have to dynamic sql I see it doing something like (this is conceptual, not actual SQL code):

```
INSERT INTO #CSV_Output          
SELECT * from #CSV_Column_Titles   
UNION ALL
EXECUTE( @Command )          -- instead of SELECT * FROM #QueryResults
```

where @Command is being built as follows:

```
Set @Command  =  'SELECT (CAST(' +  @ColumnName + ' ) as nvarchar (MAX)) as '' +  @ColumnName  +'' '
```

then appending one of these lines for each of the remaining columns of #QueryResults:

```
Set @Command =  @Command + ' , (CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' ) as nvarchar (MAX)) as '' + @ColumnName  + '' '
```

and ending with

```
Set @Command =   @Command + ' FROM #QueryResults' )
```

where @ColumnName is extracted from the temporary table that was used to create #CSV_Column_Titles.

---

Updated 20180404

(Sigh) Often in the heat of battle you can't see the forest for the trees...  I made two mistakes: assuming that the first Select * in the union would (implicitly) determine the column types of the final result set and trying to do to much in one step.

The key point in the accepted answer is to do the conversion *before* doing the union.

In my case the union is not needed, all I had to do was insert the (converted) values into #CSV_Output and pass that back to the calling script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind extra I/O, you can do this without dynamic SQL.

First, create a temporary table with the schema of your output table (using SELECT/INTO with a negative predicate). Insert Query #2 into this temporary table, so that it will implicitly convert to those target types. In your case, this is all NVARCHAR(MAX).

```
--This will create a table like #CSV_Output, to store intermediate results
SELECT * INTO #QueryResultsCast FROM #CSV_Output WHERE 0 = 1

--cast all via INSERT
INSERT INTO #QueryResultsCast
SELECT * FROM #QueryResults

--Original desired output (retrieving from #QueryResultsCast)
INSERT INTO #CSV_Output          
SELECT * from #CSV_Column_Titles   --  n" columns, all columns are nvarchar( MAX ) )
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #QueryResultsCast       --  "n" columns, all must be implicitly converted to nvarchar( MAX )
```

Comment: Many thanks, especially for the quick response, will try it tomorrow.  This looks to be perfect for what I have to do - especially since I'd prefer NOT to use dynamic SQL (the KISS rule).  It's also the last piece of the puzzle in creating a pure T-SQL procedure that can accept (almost) every type of result set/table and produce a corresponding "CSV-file-with-header-line" result set that gets used elsewhere.  Can you point me to something that explains how/why this method works?

Comment: @user1459519 It's just the type-casting rules. For the UNION, the server has to use the precedence, because it is being asked to UNION two different data sets. On the other side of the issue, for the INSERT, the targets are all NVARCHAR(MAX). Thus, the plan for insertion into those targets involves the conversion of the origin types to NVARCHAR(MAX) because it is an INSERT, not a UNION.

Comment: Aha! That makes perfect sense.  My mistake was trying to do too much in one step.  Your soulution worked like a charm, I've edited my question to reflect your solution.